# In Python: Given an original array of numbers, how would I create a new array that contains the values from the original array within a certain range?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

```
import os
import pyfits as ps
import lomb
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hdulist = ps.open('filename')

tbdata = hdulist[1].data

PDCFlux = tbdata.field(7)
PDCFlux = PDCFlux[~np.isnan(PDCFlux)]

psd,freq = lomb.lomb(Timesec,PDCFlux)
logpsd = np.log10(psd)
logfreq = np.log10(freq)

#want an associated 'slope'.

'''PDC Slope'''
PDCFluxrange = PDCFlux.all[np.log10(4*(10**(-5)))<freq<np.log10(4*(10**(-7)))]
```

In the last line, I attempted to create a new array: `PDCFluxrange` that consists of values of the array `PDCFlux` for `freq` (frequency) between: `log10(4*(10**(-5)))` and `log10(4*(10**(-7))`.

When I run the program in Pylab, I receive an error message similar to: `Value Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous`. Use `a.any()` or `a.all()`.

In which case, I am unsure of how to properly use either of these two functions in my code without creating a loop, or defining a new function; I think that there may be a simpler method to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: you should simplify your code to your question. but then again, if you simplify it, you will probably find the answer..

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a[(a > 2) & (a < 8)]
array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Each condition (`a > 2` and `a < 8`) is creating a boolean numpy array which is equal in length to `a`, and contains the truth value of your criterion at each position in `a`.

```
   >>> a > 2
   array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Then, you're using [numpy.logical_and](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) to find the positions at which *both* conditions are true.

Finally, you're using the resulting array as a [boolean or "mask" index array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to retrieve only the elements from the original array that meet your criteria.

I *think* you're getting the `ValueError` because while `a > 2` is valid (and is really just calling `a.__gt__(2)`, a statement like `2 < a < 8` is first calling `cmp(2,a)`, which results in the same `ValueError` for me:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> cmp(2,a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Thanks!
The 'and' statement was the part that I was missing. This clears it right up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
PDCFluxrange = [x for x in PDCFlux if x>np.log10(4*(10**(-5))) and x<np.log10(4*(10**(-7)))]
```

Does that work for you? I hope I'm understanding your code right.